# How to pass ID for geocoding request

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I am working on a little API, which should display markers on Google Maps. I have a database of possible markers, where I need to set longitude and latitude of the address so I can show them later on the map, without doing geocoding each time for all addresses.

I made a little utility to run it one time and cache these necessary data into database:

```
function processMissing(data) {
    var result;

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address' : data[i]['address']+','+data[i]['city']+','+data[i]['zipcode']+','+data[i]['ctrcode']}, function(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
               result = data[i]['id'] + ': ' + results[0].geometry.location);
               //Store result to database
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My only problem is, that `data[i]['id']` will of course throw data[i] undefined error, because it does not exists inside of function, which is called `async` when geocoder is done.

Question is, how can I pass this ID trough `geocoder.geocode` or how can I reach him inside of function?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use function closure to associate the id with the callback:

```
function geocodeAddress(data) {
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address' : data['address']+','+data['city']+','+data['zipcode']+','+data['ctrcode']}, function(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
               // save the result data in the input structure or write it to your database
               data['id'].result = data['id'] + ': ' + results[0].geometry.location);
               //Store result to database
            } else alert("id ="+data['id']+" could not be geocoded, status:"+status);
        });
}

function processMissing(data) {
    var result;

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
      geocodeAddress(data[i])
    }
}
```

Comment: So simple solution, and I did not see it :). Maybe the third caffee was necessary :D

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will solve your problem but I have something similar.
Let's give it a try:

```
// 2.9.1 set address
geocoder.geocode({ address: query.join(" ") }, function (result, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        // center map
        loc = result[0].geometry.location;
        options = $.extend({}, cfg.mapOptions, { center: loc });

        // set map options & markers
        myProject.initMap(options);
        myProject.ajaxGetMarkers(loc.lat(), loc.lng());
    }
});
```

My `query` object is similar to your `data[i]` object. Consider using `join(' ')`:

```
var query = data[i];
geocoder.geocode({ address: query.join(" ") }, function (result, status) {

});
```

On success, `result[0]` will give you `address_components`, `formatted_address`, `geometry` and `types`. Looks ok on your end. Just added it as extra information.

On your particular problem:
Was thinking about using an extra array which can be used to push `query` or `data[i]` but then you need 2 separate for loops. Might not be ideal.

On the other hand you could use `bind()` or `$.proxy` if you're using jQuery:

```
var query = data[i];
geocoder.geocode({ address: query.join(" ") }, $.proxy(function (result, status) {
    // this refers to query
}, query));
```

Using ECMA5 bind is added to the language [info](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/):

```
var query = data[i];
geocoder.geocode({ address: query.join(" ") }, function (result, status) {
    // this refers to query
}.bind(query));
```

`bind` is supported from IE9 ([info table](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/))
if you need older browser support consider using a [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/hendriklammers/3773114) as explained on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FFunction%2Fbind)

Comment: Thank you a lot for you extended effort, but I will use the first, simplier solution :)

Comment: I can agree with that ;)

Comment: Yay, if I could, I would acept both answers, you just helped me with that proxy on other similar problem where function closure was not a good idea. So thank you again :).